# Positioning position: fixed elements correctly after pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

Alright, this one is really stumping me. I'm looking for a way to reliably position a `position: fixed` element relative to a statically positioned element when after the user pinches to zoom.

More details: this is a problem I am running into with my jQuery plugin, [Bigfoot](http://www.bigfootjs.com). Essentially, it turns footnotes into clickable buttons that generate popovers with tooltips pointing at the button. The tooltips must be `position: fixed`; the popover is placed directly after the paragraph containing the footnote link so that the same paragraph/ image/ other styling applies to the footnote contents by default.  This means that `position: absolute`, which is easier to work with on mobile, is basically out. The script also needs to be able to reliably calculate the space between the footnote button and the top/ bottom of the visible page (so that the popover can be positioned on top or bottom, depending on which has enough space) and to the right/ left of the visible page (so that the tooltip can be positioned to actually point at the popover).

### What I've Tried

The thing that works for when the viewport is not zoomed is something along the lines of (with jQuery):

```js
var $target = $(".target");
$(".popover").css({
    top: $target.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
    left: $target.offset().left
});
```

However, this method fails to line up the elements when the viewport is scrolled. I can see what the zoom factor is by comparing the inner width (`window.innerWidth`) with the total width of the page (`document.documentElement.clientWidth`). I can also find the horizontal/vertical offsets with `window.pageXOffset/pageYOffset` (these numbers don't appear to be the actual amount of pixels the screen is scrolled horizontally when the viewport is zoomed, but I'm not really sure). However, I have not found any way to combine these pieces of information together to find the actual `left`/`top` offset values that will properly align the button with its tooltip.

### Examples

To get an idea of what the script is actually supposed to be doing (and the weird misalignments that happen as a result of zooms on mobile) you can check out the buttons on the project page (http://www.bigfootjs.com). Something that correctly aligns the `<div class='aimer'>` (that is `position: fixed`) directly over the static `<div class='target'>` when the viewport is zoomed on mobile with the following example markup is what I'm looking for (at a minimum, needs to support current mobile Safari):

#### HTML

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="aimer"></div>
        <div class="target"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.target,
.aimer {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

.target { margin: 10em 0 40em 6em; }

.aimer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help, and let me know if there is any other information I can provide!

Comment: I once spent a great deal of time researching this for myself. I tried a few things but nothing worked very well at all. Ultimately we decided to disable zooming with a meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>` and instead use CSS media queries and em's to ensure the website looked appealing without zooming.

Comment: This works for mobile browsers, but Safari desktop will misplace elements when pinched or zoomed.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for my needs. It relies on `position: absolute`, though. `position: fixed` behaves differently on chrome vs safari, in respect to viewport zoom level.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    TweenMax.set(element, {
        left: window.pageXOffset,
        top: window.pageYOffset,
        scale: 1 / ($document.width() / innerWidth),
    })
})
```